# Change color palette in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the color palette from Microsoft in combination with a XLAM Add-In.
I've found the following code from [Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.colors).

```
ActiveWorkbook.Colors = Workbooks("BOOK2.XLS").Colors
```

My code looks like this:

```
Public Sub ApplyColors()
Dim add As Workbook
Set add = ThisWorkbook
Dim act As Workbook
Set act = ActiveWorkbook
add.ResetColors
act.ResetColors
add.Colors(1) = RGB(1, 1, 1)
act.Colors = add.Colors
End Sub
```

When I run it, there are no error codes, but simply nothing happens.
I'm first reseting the colors of the AddIn (add) and Active Workbook (act). Then applying a new color and in the last step setting the color palette of AddIn to the Active Workbook.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you sure you want to change the palette? Or do you want to change the colors of the theme? Palettes are a relict from old times and hardly ever used these days.

Comment: @FunThomas good point. In this case the colors of the theme. I've already looked into it, however I don't want to have a custom theme saved somewhere on my PC but inside the add-in itself. I have found some Files with a custom color theme without a dedicated saved location, but I can't replicate the system on a standard workbook

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.
I created a custom color theme, saved it temporarily, loaded it and then deleted it.

```
Sub CreateCustomColorTheme()
Dim newTheme As ThemeColorScheme
Dim tempFile As String
tempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\MyCustomTheme.thmx"
Set newTheme = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme

'Define custom colors for each color index
newTheme.Colors(msoThemeAccent1) = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
newTheme.Colors(msoThemeAccent2) = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Green
newTheme.Colors(msoThemeAccent3) = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Blue
newTheme.Colors(msoThemeAccent4) = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Yellow
newTheme.Colors(msoThemeAccent5) = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Magenta
newTheme.Colors(msoThemeAccent6) = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Cyan

'Set custom theme as the active theme
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Save tempFile
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load tempFile
Kill tempFile
End Sub
```